# Empty bitfield member cannot be passed by Enterprise Architect

Tags: c, uml, enterprise-architect

I have a structure in `c` that looks like this:

```
typedef union AxisBitFieldStatus{
    struct {
        BitField32
                            :7,
        actuatorSaturated   :1,
                            :1,
        lastIndexInError    :2
    } bits;
    UInt32 all;
} BITS_SERVO_MODE, *P_BITS_SERVO_MODE;
```

It seems that because of the empty bitfield member (which is legal `c`) enterprise architect will throw an error when parsing this file in a reverse code engineering.

**Is there a way to add a macro or similar to successfully parse this bitfield and simply skip the empty member?**

Comment: I suppose you aren't allowed to give the bitfield a name, like `unused`.

Comment: Do be aware that C places very few constraints on how the bitfields are arranged within their containing addressible storage unit, and it does not specify the type of that addressible storage unit.  In particular, the storage unit for a given bitfield is not required to have the same type or even the same size as the declared type of the bitfield itself.  As such, I suspect that what you expect from the union you've presented is much more than what C guarantees it to provide.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, thats is fine but not what the questions is about. I cant go through and change lots and lots of legacy code today.

Comment: @user3386109 I can, but there are hundreds of these and i would prefer not to change them all.

Comment: @Ben, that's why I presented my remarks as a comment, not an answer.  Nevertheless, I am not certain I understand what you actually are looking for.  If you can't or won't change the union declaration, then that's the declaration that Enterprise Architect must deal with.  Adding macros cannot change that.  If EA can't handle it, then it might be worth filing a bug report, but of course that would be unlikely to bear fruit any time soon.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know, so thank you is probably a better response. I figured that `ea`, being the beast that it is, would have a way of adjusting the parsing rules to simply give these a name (like `empty`). I thought perhaps there would be a parsing rule macro that i could formulate. I am really looking for ideas on how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this. The parsing rules of EA cannot be changed. The solution in the end was to find and set all empty bitfield members with a name. Because the bitfields cannot have repeated members (where we had large numbers of unnamed fields in a bitfield) we developed a macro like this:

```
#define VARIABLE_FROM_PARTS_SUB(p1, p2) p1 ## p2 
#define VARIABLE_FROM_PARTS(p1, p2) VARIABLE_FROM_PARTS_SUB(p1, p2)
#define __unused_bitfield__ VARIABLE_FROM_PARTS(_b_unused, __COUNTER__)
```

Which allowed us to define the bitfields like so:

```
typedef union AxisServoModeConfiguration {
struct {
        BitField32
        __unused_bitfield__ :7,
        actuatorSaturated   :1,
        __unused_bitfield__ :1,
        lastIndexInError    :1,
        ...
```